# in Matlab: best fit a 3D plot inside a figure

Tags: matlab, graphics

How to plot a 3D ( or 2d) model ( say using plot3() in a figure so that it gets the maximum visible space available in that figure? In other words, the bounding box of the model is just about to touch the figure top, left, right and bottom corner.

Answer (score 3):

Try [axis tight or fill](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axis.html).

> axis tight sets the axis limits to the range of the data.
>
> axis fill sets the axis limits and PlotBoxAspectRatio so that the axes
>   fill the position rectangle. This option has an effect only if
>   PlotBoxAspectRatioMode or DataAspectRatioMode is manual.

Comment: That will not do it. What I need has something to do with camera manipulation.